# Meaning of comments - After adding detail to a question when receiving a warning as "closed as too broad"

Tags: discussion, comments, closed-questions, too-broad

A question edited perfectly after receiving the warning **"closed as too broad"**. So some of the sentences removed and more of the sentences added to make it perfect.

So now, what about the comments received before the question edited, as some of them will not be appropriate to current version?

Will this edited question go under verification before public view, as there will be chance to hide the existing comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once OP edits the question which was put on hold, the question gets into the reopen votes review queue. No verification (what is expected to be verified?) is made and users (with 3k+) rep can review the question.

Anyone can understand that there were some comments made which became irrelevant after the edit was made - however if you want, you can flag the thread with the custom mod-attention flag explaining that the comments are obsolete and should be removed. Though, seriously, unless the previous revisions held some criminality in them, any reviewer can accept that the comments are obsolete.

Also, in case the pushing factor was the OP's edit, the primary view provided to the reviewers in the reopen votes queue is the comparison between the current and the previous revision, and in such cases the reviewers have to look at the edit to decide whether to leave the question closed or vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

A link would help. If you have enough reputation you can flag the obsolete comments as just that, obsolete. You can also add a comment of your own that says something like "thanks, I've edited in some more detail." People looking at the question in the reopen queue will understand that the comments are for an old version of the question. There is a timestamp on your edit and on every comment, so there should be no confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can flag the entire question for moderation using the "in need of moderator intervention" option and fill in the explanation area with a request for a mod to remove the unnecessary comments. This will save you from having to flag each and every comment (assuming there are several).

They may not remove all commentary but they will likely remove anything that's no longer appropriate for the current version of the question... assuming that they agree with you that the comments are no longer germane.